# Set up Firebase Crashlytics on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I never setted crashlytics before
and when i follow officials instructions https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios&authuser=0#add-sdk i get stuck in the run script part
crashlytics version 4.6.2
[image]

in the output i get a confirmation that crashlytics is setted but in the dashboard i see nothing
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test this you can force a crash..

What you can do is...

- Add a button on view and implement its `touchupInside` event.
- in that method just write `fatalError()`
- Run your app and click on that button.(You app will crash here so it will be close)
- Now open app again(**Do not run app. Just open it by taping on app icon**)

So the crash report will be send to firebase and you can see the result on firebase dashboard with in 5 minutes(as per their doc.).

Also you need to set this flag in build setting of your project to generate dsym file for debug mode.

[image]

Also this has to be set in build phase

[image]

Comment: thanks, it works. 
just test running without xcode