# Not able to connect firebase crashlytics in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, xcode11.5

[image]

I have followed the proper steps to add the SDK and run script still getting the same messages every time I run the application. Please suggest me. Here is the code.

```
pod file :
target 'Forecupdate' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Firebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

end
```

Added the run script in the build phase:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
```

added `FirebaseApp.configure()` in `Appdelegate`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set up Firebase Crashlytics on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64365931/set-up-firebase-crashlytics-on-ios)

Comment: I have also tried the same, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I was missing **number 7**.
The steps  in case you want to go down the list and make sure you didn't miss anything:

1. Add pods to podfile.
2. `pod install.`
3. Restart xcode.
4. Add build step.
5. Change build settings to DWARF with dSYM File.
6. Add a button that calls Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash().
7. **Run the app on simulator then (make sure you stop the app in Xcode and again open on simulator by clicking app icon)**
8. Force crash the App
9. Run the app again

you will see the crash reports in crashlytics.